# Given the angle and x, how can I find Y?

Tags: math, trigonometry

Given the angle and x, how can I find Y? For example, if angle = 45 and x = 480, y = 480. How can I compute this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If its a right angle (90 degree) you can calculate using this formula

```
x/y = tan (deg)
```

From your question it seems its a right angle.

Comment: Yes, sorry, forgot to mention that. Thanks, so y = x/tan(deg)?